# Swift String encoding and NSXMLParser parsing issues

Tags: string, swift, encoding, nsxmlparser

My App is calling the free Weather Forecast web service found at this URL:
http://www.webservicex.net/globalweather.asmx/GetWeather?CityName=Boston&CountryName=United+States

I'm using the usual `NSURLConnection` and `NSXMLParser` delegate methods to parse the incoming data (I've done this a million times before) but quite strangely, the `NSMutableData` that is returned is not getting converted to a string correctly via `NSUTF8StringEncoding`.  Its basically failing to convert the "<" and ">" characters of the opening and closing XML tags, giving me "& l t;" and "& g t;" instead.

The problem seems to be in the `connectionDidFinishLoading` function:

```
func connection(connection: NSURLConnection, didReceiveData data: NSData) {        
    webServiceData!.appendData(data)
}

func connectionDidFinishLoading(connection: NSURLConnection) {
    let XMLResponseString = NSString(data: webServiceData!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)!
    println("XMLResponseString = \(XMLResponseString)")
}
```

The output I get from the `println` statement there is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<string xmlns="http://www.webserviceX.NET">&lt;?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?&gt;
&lt;CurrentWeather&gt;
  &lt;Location&gt;DALLAS EXECUTIVE AIRPORT, TX, United States (KRBD) 32-41N 096-52W 203M&lt;/Location&gt;
  &lt;Time&gt;Dec 30, 2014 - 08:53 AM EST / 2014.12.30 1353 UTC&lt;/Time&gt;
  &lt;Wind&gt; from the NE (050 degrees) at 12 MPH (10 KT):0&lt;/Wind&gt;
  &lt;Visibility&gt; 9 mile(s):0&lt;/Visibility&gt;
  &lt;SkyConditions&gt; overcast&lt;/SkyConditions&gt;
  &lt;Temperature&gt; 39.9 F (4.4 C)&lt;/Temperature&gt;
  &lt;DewPoint&gt; 34.0 F (1.1 C)&lt;/DewPoint&gt;
  &lt;RelativeHumidity&gt; 79%&lt;/RelativeHumidity&gt;
  &lt;Pressure&gt; 30.42 in. Hg (1030 hPa)&lt;/Pressure&gt;
  &lt;Status&gt;Success&lt;/Status&gt;
&lt;/CurrentWeather&gt;</string>
```

So as you can see I'm getting the first 2 tags correctly - the "< ?XML >" and "< string xmlns >" tags, but the rest are all showing up as  "& l t;" and "& g t;"

What's really strange is that its saying `encoding="utf-8"` for the first tag, but on the second line (towards the end) its saying `encoding="utf-16"`.

So I tried using `NSUTF16StringEncoding`:

```
let XMLResponseString = NSString(data: webServiceData!, encoding: NSUTF16StringEncoding)!
```

and that basically gave me chinese looking characters.

I also tried running the parser directly on the url instead of the NSMutableData that's returned, like so:

```
    myXMLParser = NSXMLParser(contentsOfURL:theURL!)!
```

(the original statement was this:

```
    myXMLParser = NSXMLParser(data:webServiceData)
```

but neither of these worked.

So what's going on here? Any suggestions on how to get this to work properly?

Answer (score 1):

This is actually the remote service being broken, rather than your code. Yes, the server really is sending XML in XML for no particularly good reason.

```
$ curl 'http://www.webservicex.net/globalweather.asmx/GetWeather?CityName=Boston&CountryName=United+States'

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<string xmlns="http://www.webserviceX.NET">&lt;?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?&gt;
&lt;CurrentWeather&gt;
  &lt;Location&gt;BOSTON LOGAN INTERNATIONAL, MA, United States (KBOS) 42-22N 071-01W 54M&lt;/Location&gt;
```

Comment: That's interesting. And strange. So how do you explain the fact that if you copy-paste the URL `http://www.webservicex.net/globalweather.asmx/GetWeather?CityName=Boston&CountryName=United+States` into your browser, you get a valid XML response? That doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: The browser is translating the &lt; into < and &gt; into >, so what you see and what is actually being returned are two different things. Their webservice seems to be 'return an XML encoded string inside another XML document' which is frankly bizzare; but that's what it does.